# How to indicate players they should click to continue?

Tags: user-experience, user-interface

My game is entirely based on single click/touch interactions. In the screenshot, the player has just clicked the toolbox and the message *"My toolbox - I better pick it up."* appeared.

I want the player to be able to take their time reading the message and decide when to continue. The next click should clear the message and the toolbox goes into the inventory.

I'm looking for ideas how to tell the player that they need to click to continue. Some controller based games put a little "A" icon behind the message to indicate a button needs to be pressed but I don't have controller input, only mouse or touch screen (with touch screen, there's no cursor either).

Should I put a little icon saying "Click!"? Other ideas? Is it OK to just let the player figure out that the next click would trigger the action?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a question you can answer by playtesting. You have two potential solutions already: an icon, or just nothing. You can try one of those solutions and test it with some players representative of your target audience to see if they figure it out or if they find it to be a barrier, as well as gauge how much they like it. That will give you more real information about what works for your audience than the opining of strangers on the Internet like us. 

Comment: That's true, yes. On the other hand, it feels like a super common problem to me and I wonder if there's a best-practice solution around I missed.

Comment: That sounds like a question you can answer by playing a few other games with click to continue mechanics and observing what they do. (Or watching let's play videos to accelerate your research) I doubt you'll find a universal best practice, but you will discover a variety of approaches that each worked for the games that used them. That's about the best we can expect in this line of work.